# generic algorithm to force range to go through zero

Tags: python

I'm looking for a generic algorithm which, given the range values `start` and `end` will generate a list of numbers, but **the numbers must go through zero.**.
Here's my current code:

```
end = 78
start = -1 * end
step_size = 16
numbers = range(start, end+step_size, step_size)

$ numbers
Out[90]: [-78, -62, -46, -30, -14, 2, 18, 34, 50, 66, 82]
```

so in this particular case, I would subtract 2 from each number, so that the numbers have one zero value. But how could I do this more generally? I'm doing this to calculate the y-tic locations of a graph, and therefore I want them to go through zero once.

Comment: Don't start with a list and make it go to zero, start with a zero and go up and down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`start % step_size` should be the required offset:

```
>>> end = 78
>>> start = -1 * end
>>> step_size = 16
>>> range(start-(start%step_size), end+step_size, step_size)
[-80, -64, -48, -32, -16, 0, 16, 32, 48, 64, 80]
```

Examples:

```
def get_range(end, step_size):
    start = -1 * end
    return range(start-(start%step_size), end+step_size, step_size)

>>> get_range(23, 4)
[-24, -20, -16, -12, -8, -4, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24]
>>> get_range(19, 11)
[-22, -11, 0, 11, 22]
>>> get_range(103, 32)
[-128, -96, -64, -32, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128]
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the minimum of the absolute value of the list, subtract it from each element of the list. This isn't the most optimal solution, but it's quick and dirty and it works:

(I used numpy because it's more efficient than lists, and if you're using matplotlib, you probably have numpy)

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> a = arange(-10, 20, 3)
>>> b = argmin([abs(_) for _ in a])
>>> a-=a[b]
>>> a
array([-9, -6, -3,  0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18])
```